# How to rebuild Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, rebuild

We have been using Rebuilder plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin) on our Jenkins and see a lot of value with that.

However, I dont see the "Rebuild" / "Rebuild with parameters" action for pipeline jobs. Am I missing a configuration / version?

If you know of any other plugin that allows re-building a pipeline job, with an ability to modify the parameters, defaulting to parameters of last run, that would be good too.

We are using Jenkins "CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise 2.46.24.0.2-fixed". Rebuilder plugin version is 1.25

Screenshots for both types of job here:

[image]

Comment: We're using Rebuilder v1.28. Works as expected - also for Pipeline and Multibranch Pipeline jobs. Did you check the Jenkins log? Maybe there has been some error while loading the plugin?

Comment: @JoergS with Rebuilder Version 1.34 I still can't see "Rebuild Last" in the Pipeline Project view.

Comment: @NoamManos: Sorry I think my comment was misleading. Please check the answer from which was marked as solution. This is how it works for us, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a Pipeline job, the rebuild option does not come at the job level. Rather it comes at job execution instance level. Click on build number to go that execution, and the option will show up, as per screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to the console output page for the respective build number, on the left you would have an option by name "replay".

Comment: A replay does not allow to provide alternate values for parameters, and correspondingly does not fulfill my needs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was not logged in to jenkins (due VPN disconnection and reconnection).
Logging in to jenkins via the top right link solved the issue for me