# Restart a Jenkins pipeline and adjust parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job based on a Jenkinfile.
I need to restart the latest job and adjust a parameter or parameters.
With plain old Jenkins jobs, I can do it using the "Rebuild Last" option.
With Jenkins files, I see "Restart from Stage", "Replay" options but they don't allow to override parameters.

Currently, I have to open a previous run and copy-paste all the parameters to new job execution.

What are possible workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Rebuilder plugin as well, but for pipelines it's available from build level, not from job level (as it was for freestyle jobs).
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956495/10721592).

Comment: I don't have the "Rebuild" option in the build level, as well. Rebuilder plugin 1.29, Jenkins ver. 2.150.1.

Comment: That's strange, I have the same Rebuilder plugin 1.29, Jenkins ver. 2.150.1 and I'm able to use "Rebuild" option for pipelines.

Comment: I still see the issue only in jobs that use https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger. Other jobs with Jenkinsfiles have the "Rebuild" option.

Comment: Don't know, probably there is some integration issue between these plugins. But to be sure, you can restart Jenkins and reinstall plugins (maybe it can help, who knows).